# Better approach to store configuration settings - in-memory or database

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a simple C# windows application, I've some standard reports and their parameters, along with configuration settings that remain constant in the application. So, I'm thinking which is the better approach to store these values.

If it is database design I can imagine through below tables

> **Report:** Id, Name
>
> **ReportParameters:** Id, Name, ReportId
>
> **Configuration**: Id, Name, Value, Environment

Report contains 5 records, and each report contains max 3 parameters and configuration contains 5 records for each environment.

For these kind of scenarios, would it be advisable to store in database or in-memory variables.

**Edit**

This windows application will be used every quarter, so IMO database + cache doesn't seem to be good idea.

Comment: You are mixing use with serialization.  You can only use variables in memory.  That is independent on if you serialize to database or XML config.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Interms of maintainability, can we consider in-memory static variables as a option ?

Comment: -1 A static variable is only in memory after is has been read from disk so how is that "store in database or in-memory variables".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do something via appSettings then since you aren't storing too much. You could also create a custom object, serialize it and then deserialize it when you need it. There are lots of different options but those are probably the first ones I would consider in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've provided some more context around its usage. It is run every quarter so having them in cache doesn't make any difference.

Comment: So this isn't asp.net then. I thought it was from the tag. I would probably do something via appSettings then since you aren't storing too much. You could also create a custom object, serialize it and then deserialize it when you need it. There are lots of different options but those are probably the first ones I would consider in your case.

Comment: If I initialize them in custom static variables, I am trying to understand why we would serialize and de-serialize.

Comment: Its a quick way to save the values to disk and then bring them back into an object when you need to. See here how: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

Comment: Thanks for the link. So, serialization is used to generate xml version of the object as one time thing and then reference the xml file inside the application and de-serialize it. Is my understanding right?

Comment: i mean when they close your app you write the settings to an xml file via serialization and then when the app starts up and needs the settings it can read them in and instantiate the object you were using before.

Comment: Why did you accept this as the answer?  This has nothing to do with web caching; it is neither web-related nor caching related.

Comment: @LaceCard originally he had it tagged as asp.net so and so it was applicable then.

Comment: @MikeCheel, can you please update the answer with your first comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: @MikeCheel, I am sorry for returning back. I came to know that this application is console application configured as scheduled job. So, in this case, is it ok to just store the serialized version directly as xml in the application and deserialize as required.

Comment: As you mentioned, if the object is serialized after the job ends then deserialize when it starts again when required. I think it doesn't add any advantage, since we need to retrieve initial data either from DB or in-memory variables, so how does serialization add value.

Comment: If in-memory variable and the computer restarts or the process hangs or someone kills the process the data is gone. A DB to hold a handful of settings is too much overheadin my book. You can store the settings in a configuration file or serialize to and from disk (it will be easier no doubt to set properties and then write to an xml file than to parse a flat file or something.

Comment: I mean since they are settings, they get initialized in static variables. I've created this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437767/serialize-a-object-to-store-configuration-settings?noredirect=1#comment25330948_17437767

Answer (score 2):

If it's in-memory, then all of your configuration will be lost every time you close the program.  Based on:

> Report contains 5 records, and each report contains max 3 parameters
>   and configuration contains 5 records for each environment.

it seems like a very minimal number of settings.  I would serialize some object to an XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are already using a database, I'd plan on just serializing the settings.  If you are using a database, this might make sense, particularly if the settings change often.  That makes it easy to just poke the database and change the settings.  Similarly if you serialize in XML.

Keeping them in the source code should be a last resort, since any report settings are likely to change or be added.  You shouldn't have to recompile the code to add a new report.